# XSL add element from another namespace to output without xmlns declaration

Tags: xml, xslt

I need elements from 2 domains in my output XML, but I don't want any xmnls attributes in the output.

My XML is:

`<p>Talking about stuff.</p>`

My XSL is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:amazon="http://www.amazon.com" exclude-result-prefixes="amazon">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<!-- root -->
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- speak element -->
    <xsl:element name="speak">
        <amazon:domain name="conversational">
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </amazon:domain>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Paragraph -->
<xsl:template match="*[local-name()='p' or local-name()='P']">
    <p><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/></p>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And my result is:

```
<speak>
   <amazon:domain xmlns:amazon="http://www.amazon.com" name="conversational">
      <p>Talking about stuff.</p>
   </amazon:domain>
</speak>
```

But I need it to be:

```
<speak>
   <amazon:domain name="conversational">
      <p>Talking about stuff.</p>
   </amazon:domain>
</speak>
```

Comment: The output you want is not well-formed XML. You cannot use a prefix without including a namespace declaration binding the prefix to a namespace URI.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I was afraid of that. Unfortunately Amazon Polly rejects the request if there are xmlns attributes in it.

Comment: I am afraid I know nothing about that. A quick search shows that they use SSML, and the [SSML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/speech-synthesis11/#S2.2.2) requires a conforming SSML document to be a well-formed XML document. So most likely you're misinterpreting their requirements. In any case, the result you show cannot be produced by an XSL transformation, unless you produce it manually (as text) - in which case you might be better off looking for another tool.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Thank-you, I appreciate the info. Amazon Polly returns an error "Invalid SSML" if the request is <speak><amazon:domain xmlns:amazon="http://www.amazon.com" name="conversational"><p>Talking about stuff.</p></amazon:domain></speak> so it looks like I'm looking other options to generate the SSML.